# Normcdf() input arguments

Tags: matlab, statistics

I am trying to solve:

> Use the technique of importance sampling via tilted densities to
> estimate the quantity where X is a standard normal random variable.
> Generate estimates for a = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.  Use sample sizes 1e3, 1e5,
> and 1e7 in each estimation.
> theta=Pr{X>a}

and my teacher gave the example code:

```
n2=1e7;
for a2=1:5
    x2=rand(1,n2(1))+a2;
    theta2(a2)=mean((x2>a2).*exp(a2^2/2-a2*x2));
end
tp2=1-normcdf(1:5);
abs(tp2-theta2)./tp2
```

but when I attempt to run it I get:

> Not enough input arguments.
>
> Error in normcdf (line 16) cdf = 0.5 * erfc(-(x-mu)/(sigma*sqrt(2)));
>
> Error in HW10 (line 18) tp2=1-normcdf(1:5);

But he didn't have any errors come up in class. I can't see what I am missing to run this.

Comment: You might need to either need to ensure that the function `normcdf()` is defined or install the Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox and use the built-in function that's apart of the toolbox. When I ran it on MATLAB R2019b it works.

Comment: Here is MATLAB's documentation on the toolbox and the function `normcdf()`: https://www.mathworks.com/products/statistics.html and https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/normcdf.html.